# why wouldnt the python file i have made an executable not open

Tags: python, terminal, executable

i have written code in python and turned it into an executable , however when i try running the executable file it opens terminal for a millisecond and closes immediately .
i used pyinstaller --onefile file name.py to convert it to an executable in the terminal
this is the code incase there is anything to add or remove

```
# this calculates the y given the q and the q when given y
# the inner if is for the forward movement (y to q)
# the outer if is for reverse movement (q to y)
import math
import sympy
from sympy import *
from math import *

def velocity (n,r,s):
    #computes the velocity of the flow
    return  (1/n)*(r**(2/3))*(sqrt(s))
print ("select the desired choice between options one and two.")
print ("for determining the discharge,q (type 1)")
print ("for determining the height of the water level in a trench,y (type 2)")

choice = input ("type desired calculation: ")

if choice == ("1"):

            print("trench shapes include triangular, rectangular and trapezoidal.")
            shape = input("enter shape of trench: ")


            # triangular
            if shape == ("triangular"):
                    y = float(input("enter the height of the water level,y: "))
                    x = float(input("enter the deviation of the slope,x: "))
                    s = float(input("enter value of the bottom slope,S: "))
                    n = float(input("enter value of mannings coeficient: "))

                    r = (x*y)/(2* sqrt(1 + (x**2)))
                    A = x*(y**2)
                    v = velocity(n,r,s)
                    q = A * v
                    print("the discharge q is " + str(round(q,2)))

            #rectangular
            elif shape == ("rectangular"):
                    b =  float(input("enter length of base of trench,b: "))
                    y =  float(input("enter height of water in trench,y: "))
                    s = float(input("enter value of the bottom slope,S: "))
                    n = float(input("enter value of mannings coeficient,n: "))

                    R =  (b*y)/(b + 2*y) #hydraulic radius
                    A =  b*y  #area
                    v =  velocity(n,R,s)
                    q = A*v
                    print("the discharge q is " + str(round(q,2)))


            #trapezoidal
            elif shape == ("trapezoidal") :
                    b = float(input("enter the length of the base,b: "))
                    y = float(input("enter the height of the water level,y: "))
                    x = float(input("enter the deviation of the slope,x: "))
                    s = float(input("enter value of the bottom slope,s: "))
                    n = float(input("enter value of mannings coeficient,n: "))


                    R = ((b + x*y) *y)/(b + 2*y*sqrt((1 + (x**2)))) #hydraulic radius
                    A = (b + x*y)*(y) #area
                    v = velocity(n,R,s)
                    q =  A*v
                    print ("the discharge q is " + str(round(q ,2)))
            else :
                print ("Please enter available trench shape.")

elif choice == ("2"):
            print("trench shapes include triangular, rectangular and trapezoidal.")
            shape = input("enter shape of trench: ")

            # triangular
            if shape == ("triangular"):
                q = float(input("enter the value of the discharge,q: "))
                x = float(input("enter the value of the incline slope,x: "))
                s = float(input("enter the value of the bottom slope,s: "))
                n = float(input("enter the value of mannings coefficient,n: "))

                y = (4 * ((q * n) ** 3) * (1 + x ** 2)) / ((x ** 5) * (s ** (3 / 2)))
                y = y ** (1 / 8)
                print("the height of the water in the trench,y, is: " + str(round(y, 2)))

            # rectangular
            elif shape == ("rectangular"):
                q = float(input("enter the value of the discharge,q: "))
                b = float(input("enter length of base of the trench,b: "))
                s = float(input("enter the value of the bottom slope,s: "))
                n = float(input("enter the value of mannings coefficient,n: "))

                y = Symbol('y', postive=True)
                eq = Eq(q, (1 / n) * (((b * y) / (b + 2 * y)) ** (2 / 3)) * (sqrt(s) * (b * y)))
                m = solve(eq, y)
                m1 = m[0]
                print("the height of the water in the trench,y, is " + str(round(m1, 2)))

            # trapezoidal
            elif shape == ("trapezoidal"):
                q = float(input("enter the value of the discharge,q: "))
                b = float(input("enter length of base of the trench,b: "))
                x = float(input("enter the value of the incline slope,x: "))
                s = float(input("enter the value of the bottom slope,s: "))
                n = float(input("enter the value of mannings coefficient,n: "))

                y = Symbol('y')
                eq = Eq(q, (1 / n) * (((y * (b + x * y)) / (b + 2 * y * sqrt(1 + x ** 2))) ** (2 / 3)) * (sqrt(s)) * (y * (b + x * y)))
                m = nsolve(eq, y, 0)
                print("the height of the water in the trench,y, is " + str(round(m,2)))

            else:
                print("Please enter available trench shape.")

else:
    print ("Please type 1 or 2.")
```

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: im using windows 11

Comment: Try opening the file in the terminal, not double clicking it and tell me what it does.

Comment: i donot know how to .its my first time working with command line

Comment: open your terminal, cd into the directory of the executable (`cd \path\to\exe`) run `start [executable name]`

Comment: it gives me this error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hydraulics(msafiri).py", line 5, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sympy'
[11300] Failed to execute script 'hydraulics(msafiri)' due to unhandled exception!

Comment: Well, there's your answer. The terminal closes immediatly after program exit if you launch by double clicking. Your program exits due to the error.

Comment: and do you know any methods of fixing it

Comment: Does it run correctly when you run it without pyinstaller?